# Using 'extern' for creating array in C

Tags: c, extern

I have used `extern` for creating an array but seems it's giving me an error

> "undefined reference to `callback_Task'"

```
// test.h
typedef struct {
  uint32_t count;
  uint32_t total;
} callback_task;

extern volatile callback_task callback[10];
```

Now in C source file

```
// test.c
void test_task(void) {
  callback[1].count = 1;
  callback[1].total = 2;
}
```

While compiling its giving an error:

> undefined reference to `callback' at 'test_task'

Comment: Did you included `test.h` in `test.c` file?

Comment: The `extern` keyword makes it a *declaration*. You still need a *definition* somewhere.

Comment: Also, why are you using `volatile`?

Comment: Yes. included test.h

Answer (score 0):

An `extern` declaration doesn't create the array anywhere. It's merely an instruction to the compiler/linker to look for the variable somewhere.

You must *define* it, without `extern`, in some translation unit you will be linking your program with.

A good candidate would seem to be `test.c`, like this:

```
volatile callback_task callback[10];

void test_task(void) {
  callback[1].count = 1;
  callback[1].total = 2;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. if I remove extern, then its working... but just a question.. if I want to use outside of class then I need to make it extern.. right ?

Comment: @JigneshPanchal - I did not say to remove `extern` from the h file. I said to add a completely independent line to the c file.

Comment: @JigneshPanchal there is no such thing as a class in C.

Comment: @JigneshPanchal - If you remove `extern` and include the header *only* in test.c, it works. If you include that version in several .c files, you will get duplicate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** It's not the compiler, it's the linker complaining about the `callback` variable M.I.A. status.

---

To elaborate, a statement like

```
 extern volatile callback_task callback[10];
```

tells the compiler that "somewhere there exists" a variable `callback` with type `callback_task [10]`. It's a **"declaration"**, It does not "define" a variable on it's own. So, the existence is "known", not "proven".

Later, while linker is searching for the "actual" variable, it does not get one, and hence the error.